# Regular expression for date format DD/MM/YYYY and MM/YYYY

Tags: regex, date-format

This is the regex for DD/MM/YYYY format:

```
(?([0-9]{2})\)?[\/ ]?([0-9]{2})[\/ ]?([0-9]{4})
```

I need to allow for MM/YYYY as well as DD/MM/YYYY, please.

Note: just simply allowing numerical input only - not testing for correctness of the date, just the format...

Comment: what is the `?` doing at the start?

Comment: Does your regex work? What is the question?

Comment: what language are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget to put start `^` and end `$` anchors while doing validation.

```
^(?:([0-9]{2})[\/ ]?)?([0-9]{2})[\/ ]?([0-9]{4})$
```

`(?:([0-9]{2})[\/ ]?)?` at the first makes the day part as optional.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aB2vZ7/3)

Comment: using your answer i try to make a regexp for YYYY, MM/YYYY and DD/MM/YYYY :

^(?:([0-9]{2})[\/]?)?(?:[0-9]{2})?[\/]?([0-9]{4})$

Answer (score 0):

```
\(?([0-9]{2})?\)?[\/ ]?([0-9]{2})[\/ ]?([0-9]{4})
```

Try this.the `(?` in the start of your regex is `\(?`.Just make the group inside escaped parenthesis  optional.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/dK1xR4/10